# Send file by sftp

Tags: php, ubuntu, ftp, sftp

Under an Ubuntu machine I wanted to create a script that allows me to send a file via SFTP. For this I use the following code:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('XXX', 22);

if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'USER', 'PASS')) {
  echo "Authentication Successful!\n";
} else {
  die('Authentication Failed...');
}
```

for a first resulting:

```
Warning: ssh2_auth_password(): Authentication failed for ...
```

I thought from reading a lot of tutorials that extending ssh2.so missing. So I installed it and still no results.

Comment: correct username and paswword could help with connection

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ssh2 based functions I would suggest [phpseclib, a pure PHP SFTP implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/).

Using phpseclib you can do:

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.com');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $sftp->pwd() . "\r\n";
$sftp->put('filename.ext', file_get_contents('localfile.data'););
print_r($sftp->nlist());
?>
```

Comment: I dont now when i can download the SFTP class, help pleaz

Comment: Result: Login Failed, but in CMD it works very well, the parameters connexions is correct ... :(

Comment: @FzhEmca: You can download it from http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpseclib/files/phpseclib0.2.1a.zip/download

Answer (score -2):

You can use the stream mechanism: adress the destination file as

`$dest = "ftps://user:pwd@server.com/destinationfile.txt"`

and then use the standard php `copy` function:

```
copy($from, $dest)
```

Comment: -1. [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) is not the same as [FTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS).

Comment: it gives this erreor : Warning: copy() [function.copy]: connect() failed: Connection refused in